# Product Drop - Schedule Specific Time

Tags: magento2, schedule, time

We are using Magento 2

We sometimes have product drops with anticipated demand from social media with a specific time it will be available to purchase on our website

Currently we have been listing the product in a category (out of stock) many hours before - and then an hour before we want it to go live putting it in stock

However, this method is inconsistent with the time it takes to appear and appears in the catalog search long before it does in the category and before the specific launch time so subsequently we are getting orders prior to the official launch

**Please could people recommend ways to get around this and have the product appear exactly at a specific time?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try scheduled update. Save the product as disabled by default. Then click on "Schedule New Update" button at the same product edit page and add the exact date and time values when you want to see the product live. Choose "enable  product" as "Yes" and save schedule